# editing page before appearing in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser

Is it possible to change how to webpage will look on the web browser using vb.net and hide other elements that I don't like to show. it's like viewing website using mobile phone. I want my web browser to look different from the actual page but I'm the one who will design.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
' Dim HTML As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

  Dim HTML As String = "<H2>World</H2><P>Hai</P>"
  Dim Element1 As String = "<H2>World</H2>"
  Dim Element2 As String = "<H1>Hello</H1>"

  Dim HTML_RemovedElement As String = HTML.Replace(Element1, "")

  Dim HTML_AddedElement As String = HTML.Insert(HTML.LastIndexOf(Element1), Element2)

  MsgBox(HTML & vbNewLine & HTML_RemovedElement & vbNewLine & HTML_AddedElement)
```